# I'm trying to pass a string from my first ViewController to my second ViewController but it returns NULL

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, string

In my first view controller I have 3 input fields each of them take the user input into and saves it into a string such as: address, username and password as `NSUserDefaults`. This part works fine.
In my second view controller I'm trying to take the 3 strings from first controller (address, username and password) create a html link based on the 3 strings. I've tried many ways to access the 3 strings with no luck, the result I get is `NULL`.
Here is my code:

//.h file - first view controller with the 3 input fields `CamSetup.h`

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @interface CamSetup : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> 
 {
    NSString * address;
    NSString * username;
    NSString * password;

    IBOutlet UITextField * addressField;
    IBOutlet UITextField * usernameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField * passwordField; 
 }

 -(IBAction) saveAddress: (id) sender;
 -(IBAction) saveUsername: (id) sender;
 -(IBAction) savePassword: (id) sender;

 @property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *addressField;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *usernameField;
 @property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *passwordField; 
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *address; 
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *username; 
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *password;

 @end
```

//.m file - first view controller CamSetup.m

```
#import "CamSetup.h"

@interface CamSetup ()
@end

@implementation CamSetup
@synthesize addressField, usernameField, passwordField, address, username, password;

-(IBAction) saveAddress: (id) sender
{
address = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:addressField.text];
[addressField setText:address];
NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultAddress = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[stringDefaultAddress setObject:address forKey:@"stringKey1"];
NSLog(@"String [%@]", address);
}

-(IBAction) saveUsername: (id) sender
{
  username = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:usernameField.text];
  [usernameField setText:username];
  NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultUsername = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [stringDefaultUsername setObject:username forKey:@"stringKey2"];
  NSLog(@"String [%@]", username);
}

-(IBAction) savePassword: (id) sender
{
  password = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:passwordField.text];
  [passwordField setText:password];
  NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultPassword = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [stringDefaultPassword setObject:password forKey:@"stringKey3"];
  NSLog(@"String [%@]", password);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
[addressField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey1"]];
[usernameField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey2"]];
[passwordField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey3"]];

[super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

//.h second view controller LiveView.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "CamSetup.h"
 @interface LiveView : UIViewController
 {
  NSString *theAddress;
  NSString *theUsername;
  NSString *thePassword;
  CamSetup *camsetup; //here is an instance of the first class
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theUsername;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thePassword;

@end
```

//.m second view LiveView.m file

```
#import "LiveView.h"
@interface LiveView ()
@end

@implementation LiveView
@synthesize theAddress, theUsername, thePassword;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad]; 
  theUsername = camsetup.username; //this is probably not right?
  NSLog(@"String [%@]", theUsername); //resut here is NULL
  NSLog(@"String [%@]", camsetup.username); //and here NULL as well
}
@end
```

Comment: The camsetup variable is not initialised in your second view controoler?

Comment: hello... @Dashony i am asking to u...

Comment: sorry for the delay @Rajneesh071 I'm new to stack overflow.com and I didn't see your message until now. I had a few bugs in my code, as you can see above but what it worked for me so I don't geT NULL values but get the actual values, The solution was also this: I had to implement this code in LiveView.m : [code]   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        _theAddress = [defaults objectForKey:@"addressKey"];
        _theUsername = [defaults objectForKey:@"usernameKey"];
        _thePassword = [defaults objectForKey:@"passwordKey"];[code]

Comment: I'll try to format the code a bit better so you can see: so implement this code in LiveView.m : [code] (NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        _theAddress = [defaults objectForKey:@"addressKey"];
        _theUsername = [defaults objectForKey:@"usernameKey"];
        _thePassword = [defaults objectForKey:@"passwordKey"];)[code]

Comment: sorry, can't make it so you can see as code better but hope you can see those 4 lines of code. Good luck

Comment: i just want to know how do you using "setObject" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 5 issues in this code:

1. If you are using ARC, all the "retain" in your @properties should be changed to "strong"
2. You name your iVars and properties the same thing. (common bad practice)
3. You are always directly accessing iVars and not properties in your code.
4. You don't retain your instance of CamSetup in the second object.
5. The direct cause of your problem: in the second object you've only created a placeholder for a CamSetup instance, you've not created one nor passed one to it! self.camSetup in your second object is empty right now.

Let's go step by step:

First, give your iVars different names from your properties. This is best practice, especially for a beginner! :)

> ```
> @interface CamSetup : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> 
> {
>     NSString *_address;
> }
> @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
> @end
>
> @implementation CamSetup
> @synthesize address=_address;
> ...
> @end
> ```

This is important, because you've setup properties, but in your code, you are not using them, you are directly accessing your iVars. Since you've named them the same thing, you might not see this.

Let's look at your first object. Every "address" in your code is going to your iVar and not property. Generally, you want to access the iVars via your properties unless you're sure otherwise. The @synthesize creates a getter and setter method for your iVar that will retain the var because you told it to in your @property statement. However, when you directly access your iVar's you're not going through those accessors and thus the stuff you wrote in your @properties doesn't matter. You could end up misunderstanding a lot of errors and bugs if you aren't clear about this. In your first object this worked anyway because the alloc/init sets a retain on the object, but I noticed you *always* do this, and that's going to get you into trouble.

Here's what the saveAddress: method would look like using properties:

```
-(IBAction) saveAddress: (id) sender
{
   self.address = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:self.addressField.text];
   [self.addressField setText:self.address];
   NSUserDefaults *stringDefaultAddress = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [stringDefaultAddress setObject:self.address forKey:@"stringKey1"];
   NSLog(@"String [%@]", self.address);
}
```

Next, in your second object you need to set properties for the CamSetup instance! Right now, you just have an iVar.

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "CamSetup.h"
 @interface LiveView : UIViewController
 {
  NSString *_theAddress;
  NSString *_theUsername;
  NSString *_thePassword;
  CamSetup *_camSetup; //here is an instance of the first class
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CamSetup *camSetup; // in synthesize we'll specify that this property uses the _camSetup iVar
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theAddress;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theUsername;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thePassword;

@end
```

The implementation:

```
#import "LiveView.h"
@interface LiveView ()
@end

@implementation LiveView
@synthesize camSetup = _camSetup;
@synthesize theAddress = _theAddress;
@synthesize theUsername = _theUsername;
@synthesize thePassword = _thePassword;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad]; 
  self.theUsername = self.camSetup.username; //this is probably not right?
  // well, it's better now, but where is camSetup coming from??? it's undefined now
  NSLog(@"String [%@]", self.theUsername); //resut here is NULL
  NSLog(@"String [%@]", self.camSetup.username); //and here NULL as well
}
@end
```

We've created an iVar and property pair that will hold a pointer to a CamSetup instance and will retain that pointer (if we set it using the property). However, where is that CamSetup instance being created? Where do you alloc/init it?

There are many possible answers to this question. If CamSetup had getters for address, username, password that read them back in from your user defaults, then all you'd have to do is alloc/init a CamSetup and set it to camSetup. However, right now your first object has no functionality to retrieve the saved data so we can't do that. (still, this is the solution I'd hope you'd implement).

You might be initializing both of these in your app delegate? However, if you are using storyboard then likely it is initializing these object for you when it initializes your interface. In this case, in your appDelegate app has finished launching... method, you'll have to retrieve pointers to these instances, then the camSetup property on your second object, to point to the first. To tell you how to do this, we'd have to know detailed specifics of your app. Still, this wouldn't be doing it the best way.

Best practice would be to create an object which saves and retrieves these data from user defaults for you. This future proofs your implementation should you later want to change the way you store these data. You'd just change the way they are stored/retrieved within their class.

Comment: WOW, You just helped me do a massive cleanup. I have implemented everything you said. The second controller, I've created it using stoyboard, so I've implemented a button in the first controller which when pushed (touch up inside) opens the second controller. I know I'm almost there now but still need to get it to work. Would you be happy to help me create this other object to store and retrieve data from the user defaults? That would be greatly appreciated. And thank you so much for your help so far!!!

Comment: Now that you see the difference between iVars and Properties, the magic of properties ;p can help you create the object you want. @synthesize can create the getter and setter methods (called accessors) for your properties, but you can WRITE YOUR OWN! That means that inside the getter methods for, say username, you can have it check if the iVar has a value, and if not, read it from user defaults, set the iVar, and then return it. Give it a try. If you have trouble, create a question for that and I'll help. We're beyond the scope of this question now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, hopefully I'll finally manage to pass those values from the first controller/class to the second, as that's that my initial problem was. Thanks for your help so far. Really appreciate it Rob_vH !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
CamSetup *camsetup; //here is an instance of the first class
```

You aren't doing anything to make `camsetup` refer to the *same* instance of the `CamSetup` class that is taking input from the user. The `camsetup` variable is never initialized, hence it's NULL, hence any properties you try to retrieve from it will also be NULL.

How exactly you'd fix this depends on the structure of your program. One possibility is to have whatever code is creating the `LiveView` controller set the `camsetup` value. For example:

```
LiveView *liveViewController  = [LiveView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LiveView" bundle:nil]];
liveViewController.camsetup = camSetupController;
```

(you'd need to make `camsetup` a property to do this).

BUT, from a design standpoint, having the one view controller have a reference to the other is probably the wrong way to go about solving this problem -- it introduces unnecessary dependencies between the two controllers. For example, say you later decide to make it possible to go directly to the `LiveView` controller upon program launch, using a saved name/password; you can't do that if `LiveView` depends on getting its input from a `CamSetup` object.

So, a better approach might be to have `LiveView` take its input from `NSUserDefaults`, and/or by having the code that's calling `LiveView` set the username/password properties.

-- edit --

For example, retrieve the data from the user defaults like:

```
self.address = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey1"];
```

Comment: It sounds like you fully understand my problem, I was actually going to make the app to launch into LiveView so the user doesn't have to see the input fields every time it opens the app once the data is saved into the NSUserDefaults. But my question here is how do I make LiveView take its input from NSUserDefaults ??? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the camsetup initialized? If not -- initialize it first.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, most of which depend on how the two controllers are related to each other (like how are you going from the first to the second).

However, in your case you don't need to pass the string at all, since you are saving them in user defaults. Just read the values of those defaults in your second controller.

Comment: The default strings are: address, username, password. They belong to the first class CamSetup. How can I read them into my second class LiveView ? Also I wanted to mention the connection between the 2 ViewControllers. In the first controller I have a Button which is linked as "modal" to open the second view once pushed, and is done via storyboard only.

Comment: You read them just like you did in the viwDidLoad method. It doesn't matter which class you read them from, they are available everywhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got your problem just do one thing.
When you are setting value in `NSUserDefaults` it need `synchronization`  so just `synchronize` it.

```
[stringDefaultUsername synchronize];
```

And retrieve data using

```
NSString *username =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringKey2"];
```

Follow apple [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info